# Selecting a substring of nvarchar max

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column that's nvarchar (max).  I want to search this column to see if a specific statement is made.  I can do this by:

```
SELECT sectionText
FROM Section
WHERE sectionText LIKE '%This statement is true%'
```

However, this returns the entire section text.  I want it to only return the 50 characters before and 50 characters after this statement in a single column.

Comment: That is a strange requirement but easy enough. You would use substring and charindex.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:

```
--This line would replace your phrase
SELECT REPLACE(sectionText,'This statement is true','')
FROM Section ;

--Another way...
--Assuming your column is: 50 characters + ' ' + 'This statement is true' + ' ' + The other 50 characters
SELECT  SUBSTRING(sectionText, 1, 50) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(sectionText, 74, 50)
FROM Section 
WHERE sectionText LIKE '%This statement is true%';
```

You can check this MSDN link for more [info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/en-en/library/ms187748.aspx).
Let me provide quick examples:

```
SELECT x = SUBSTRING('abcdef', 2, 3)

SELECT x= SUBSTRING('abcdef', 2,1)  + SUBSTRING('abcdef', 5,1)
```

Thanks to @SeanLange comments (a better approach):

```
DECLARE @sectionText VARCHAR(1200) = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut a dui quam. Sed pretium purus sed lorem volutpat fringilla. Sed imperdiet sodales justo, sed suscipit mi maximus ac. Aenean ligula quam, gravida a eleifend a, vulputate nec dolor. Donec sit amet mi in justo mollis mollis eu ac magna. Integer dolor nulla, mollis eu tempus et, lobortis in libero. Etiam vitae pulvinar mauris. Curabitur a nulla orci. This statement is true. Nam non est nec urna aliquam gravida. Sed diam lorem, finibus eu arcu et, iaculis ullamcorper diam. Sed vitae tellus odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas lobortis consequat erat. Fusce aliquam imperdiet.';
DECLARE @MyPattern varchar(10) = 'This statement is true'; 

DECLARE @firstPosition INT, @lastPosition INT, @gambit INT, @textLenght INT;

--Grabbing the positions
SET @firstPosition = CHARINDEX(@sectionText, @sectionText,49)
SET @gambit = LEN(@MyPattern)
SET @lastPosition = @firstPosition + (@gambit + 1); --Sum 1 because of a White Space of a 
SET @textLenght = LEN(@sectionText);

SELECT  SUBSTRING(@sectionText, 1, @firstPosition) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@sectionText, @lastPosition, @textLenght) AS [CleanText]
--FROM Section 
--WHERE sectionText LIKE '%This statement is true%';
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the string found begins at position 100. It is certainly the right direction but not robust enough to capture what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I took the time to read and you are right @SeanLange, I wanted to develop a snippet, but CHARINDEX() is not working for me on large VARCHAR, do you know why?

Comment: You got hosed because the string you are trying to search for is not in your variable. Your variable is declared as varchar(175) but your string doesn't start until the 410th position. This means there is a silent truncation of your variable. Chance sectionText to be MUCH longer.

Comment: SELECT CHARINDEX(@MyPattern, @sectionText)

Comment: Right, my mistake was considering the number of word when generating the [text](http://lipsum.com/). Thanks for your time man

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was able to do:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(sectionText, CHARINDEX('This statement is true', sectionText)-50, 100)
FROM Section
WHERE sectionText LIKE '%This statement is true%'
```

Comment: This doesn't meet your requirements either. but it is really close. You said you want the 50 characters after the value you are searching for. You would need to add the len(SearchVal) to length of substring, not just 100.